# Для чего могут использоваться CS_BYTEALIGNCLIENT и CS_BYTEALIGNWINDOW?

Tags: winapi

В MSDN написано, что эти стили выравнивают окно или клиентскую область по границе байта памяти. Не совсем понятно, для чего это делается и в каких случаях используется (хотя бы примерно)?

Comment: Пишут, что для ускорения операций bitblt

Comment: известно, что процессор быстрее обрабатывает массивы, если они выровнены (например, по адресу, кратному 16). В этом случае можно применять всякие sse, которые дадут хороший прирост. Если же адрес не выровненный, то приходиться аккуратно обрабатывать хвосты.

Comment: KoVadim и alexlz, спасибо большое, теперь стало понятно их назначение.

Comment: Если правильно помню, это наследие еще Win3.x, когда пиксель часто был меньше байта в 16-цветном или монохромном и т.п. режимах, а графика была медленной. Вот там и возникал такой эффект хвостов при обращении к видеопамяти, особенно при заливке и копировании областей.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Путем сбора рассеянной информации по интернету получил такую картину: по историческим причинам сохранены флаги класса окна CS_BYTEALIGNCLIENT и CS_BYTEALIGNWINDOW, которые использовались для ускорения отрисовки окна в старых версиях windows и позволяли ему занимать только целое число байт в видеопамяти. Сейчас, при хранение используется глубина цвета кратная байту и эти флаги эффекта уже не имеют. Так же они не имеют эффекта при использовании функции bitblt по этой же причине.

Спасибо всем комментировавшим, вы мне очень помогли.